# Limit of univalent function on annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume $f_n$ is a univalent function defined on $\{z:\frac{1}{n} < |z|<n\}$($n\geq 2$), such that $f_n(1)=1$, $f_n$ has no zero. And the image of each $f_n$ separating $0$ from $\infty$. Prove that $f_n$ converges to the identity or $\frac{1}{z}$ pointwise.

---

I try to put $g_n(z)=\frac{1}{n}f_n(nz)$, then $g_n$ is defined on $\{z: \frac{1}{n^2}<|z|<1\}$. So $g_n$ keep $z=\frac{1}{n}$ invariant. But it seems useless. Any help or hint? Thank you.

Edit: Montel normal family theorem may be work? $f_n$ can be viewed as a family of holomorphic functions which not take value $0,1,\infty$, defined on $\{z:\frac{1}{n}<|z|<n\}-\{1\}$.